# Person from/for/with/at organization

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Is there anyone who can tell me the difference between the following sentences?

> A. The official from X association
>
> B. The official for X association
>
> C. The official with X association
>
> D. The official at X association

I tried to google this but couldn't find a good reference.

Answer (score 4):

> A. The official from X association

The person that I am talking about is coming *from* that association. I probably expect that person to act, while they are here, *on behalf* of that organisation.

> B. The official for X association

That is one of our own people, not a member of, or acting for that association. It it the person, that for us, keeps in contact and deals with that association.

> C. The official with X association

More or less the same as A), but in this case it is certainly true that the person is here in their role as member or representative of the association. You might hear this phrase on a news-item, if someone is called upon as an expert: "And to answer some questions about X, here is ms. Y, who is with the X association."

> D. The official at X association

The person is working for, or physically at the premises of X association, but I am not necessarily talking to or otherwise communication with them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This is so comprehensible! I'm so glad I asked here. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose those usage examples could be helpful:

- A: The official (coming) from X association is in the waiting room.
- B: The official (is working) for X association now.
- C/D: The official (works) with/at X association since 1999.

Comment: Wow. How simple! Thank you so much for the explanation.